# No apparent periodicity - how to create forecast?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm relatively new to time-series analysis and forecasting, and am facing a problem. I have been asked to create a forecast model for the below data ("Totals" in Fig. 1), but don't think that there is any periodicity in the data. I did a Fourier analysis of it (see Fig. 2), and again don't think that there are cycles etc in this data set. I'm afraid the source data is confidential, so I am not allowed to share it.

Can I still use e.g. Holts-Winters or ARIMA for this?

Another idea I had was to transform this into a regression problem, using (weakly correlated) lagged (i.e. from previous months) factors as input, and Totals as the dependent variable. However, this also doesn't produce good results.

Thank you for any help, tips or suggestions!!

[image: The totals (y-axis) over time (x-axis). I'm afraid I am not allowed to share the original data for this.]
[image: FFT of Totals. I cannot detect any periodicity in this. I'm afraid I am not allowed to share the original data for this.]

Comment: You don't need to add a seasonal component in the model, you could just use AR and MA processes.

Answer (score 1):

HW and SARIMA require cycles of prespecified length. For instance, if you have monthly data, you would prespecify `frequency=12`, and if you have daily data and suspect weekly seasonality, you would use `frequency=7`.

So what seasonality to allow the algorithm to use will depend on your time buckets - the algorithm itself should then sort out whether or not to use seasonality. You can use seasonal plots (see [here](https://otexts.org/fpp2/seasonal-plots.html) and [here](https://otexts.org/fpp2/seasonal-subseries-plots.html)) to explore potential seasonality. You may also have [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), which is a whole other cup of tea.

Incidentally, I strongly recommend `auto.arima` and `ets` in the `forecast` package in R, rather than trying to detect seasonality "by hand", or *always* running a seasonal method like Holt-Winters.

If you have cycles of varying, irregular or unknown length, then HW and ARIMA are not very good tools (except as simple benchmarks, which may be hard to beat). If you really want to forecast something like this, you will need to apply econometric tools - econometricians deal with such cycles in the business cycle.

That said, your top time series looks a bit strange. Specifically, the flat lines do. Did you really measure exactly the same value at multiple time points in a row, or did you measure at irregularly spaced time points and then carry the last observation forward? If so, then ARIMA and smoothing are probably not appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!

Yes, in the middle of the top plot, I had to create a few values by extrapolating because the original values there were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seams the process is moving from one stable state to another. So a logistic substitution model makes sense.

You then may fit a [logistic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), $y(t) = \frac {M}{1+e^{- \alpha (t-t_0)}}+ b$.

Find the best values of parameters $M$, $b$, $\alpha$ and $t_0$ so that the error $\sum [y(t)-x(t)]^2$ is minimum.

Once the parameters $M$, $b$, $\alpha$ and $t_0$ are estimated, compute the residuals $\epsilon(t) = y(t) - x(t)$ and look for a seasonality on these residuals.

At first glance you have a seasonality at least on the last third of the curve.